# View who liked a song on soundcloud api?

Tags: api, http, soundcloud

I want to access a list of who liked a certain sound. I know that with users, you can go to their /followers JSON and retrieve info on the user's followers, 50 users at a time. Is there a way to do that with likes on a single sound?

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks